# Android adding fingerprint support excludes some devices in play store

Tags: android, google-play, android-fingerprint-api

My android app supports minimumSDKVersion 19. Later we added fingerprint support and with following permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT" />
<uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.fingerprint"
        android:required="false" />
```

The app's targetSdkVersion is 27.
 When publishing a new version of the application in the play store many devices are excluded.

Can someone help me out whether any other manifest configuration needed to be added?
[image]

Comment: some devices mean which doesn't support fingerprint right?

Comment: @jiteshmohite I have added the screenshot. But not sure which devices are excluded

Comment: remove <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT" /> and check whether you fingerprint funtionality working or not.

Comment: Please recheck android: required="false" under uses-feature ..because if u put android:reqired=" true" then it will eliminate the device which doesn't support fingerprint.so it could be the reason devices may exclude by play store,

Comment: it not because of fingerprint feature that some device are excluded , it’s because of your api version , api 19 is for Android 4.4 , if you want to support more device change your minimumSdk to 14 and you can support more device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT" />
```

use below permission to support backward compatibility and it will not exclude devices when publishing in play store.

```
<uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT" />
```